# C# WPF MVVM column filtering use of textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, datatable

In an MVVM pattern, I have 16 different strings bound to 16 textboxes for filtering columns, each of which has propertychanged assigned at creation. The logic fails due the remaining fields still being null as default at runtime. I want to ignore the null fields. If I fill every single field in the list, then it work as expected.

**What I want:** if the user randomly chooses box 1, 5, and 15 to fill with text, then it should only take those for filtering, and ignore the remaining empty ones. If the user does not fill anything, then it should continue showing the whole table.

**What I've tried:** I've tried to take all fields and set != "" and != null before it's added to a list, and then return the list type as string for filtering. Making a foreach didn't help either. See the example below:

```
public List<String> FilterList()
    {

        List<String> filters = new List<string>();

        if (!Filterbox1.Equals("") && !Filterbox1.Equals(null))
        {
            filters.Add(Filterbox1);
        }

        if (!Filterbox2.Equals("") && !Filterbox2.Equals(null))
        {
            filters.Add(Filterbox2);
        }

        return filters;   
    }
```

The original code that I tried to work with:

```
 string[] ColumnFilter = new[] { Filterbox1, Filterbox2, Filterbox3, Filterbox4, Filterbox5, Filterbox6, Filterbox7, Filterbox8, Filterbox9, Filterbox10, Filterbox11, Filterbox12, Filterbox13, Filterbox14, Filterbox15, Filterbox16 };

 _dataGridModel.DataTableMergeren = new DataView(MainTable).ToTable(false, ColumnFilter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the best way to do it is using something like this:

```
public List<string> FilterList(string[] FilterBoxes)
    {
        List<string> R = FilterBoxes.Where(x => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x) == false).ToList<string>();
        return R;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Changed it to:

        public string[] FilterList(string[] FilterBoxes )
        {
            string[] R = FilterBoxes.Where(x => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x) == false).ToArray();
            return R;
        }

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize your TextBoxes you should do something like Filterbox1.Text = String.Empty or something similar. That should allow you to reference them without getting an error (and not have to do a null check).

However that still doesn't fix the code efficiency. I recommend learning User Controls, and running a loop to create 16 of them when the program starts. Then you can avoid having unique names for 16 TextBoxes that are essentially the same thing.

Comment: It's not allowed to pre-define the textbox by pointing directly on the Filterbox in the view, when using the MVVM patteren. 

The strings are already binded when the program starts, but then the strings (textbox) are nulls when fetching the columns on event. It's the XAML that's define the content, when fetching data from user input. I haven't seen anything quick in XAML that pre-defines it as empty on startup.  using the TargetNullValue='' doesn't help either.